# In my React application, I'm using a popover component from material ui. Hovering over the icon does not open the popover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popover

I'm having trouble figuring this out.  My I've implemented a popover component, where, when the user hovers over an 'i' icon, a popover should open, when the user hovers away from the icon, it should close the popover.  What I think is happening is that while hovering over the icon, the open and close methods are constantly being called so it looks like its never being opened.

My component:

```
export const InfoIconWrapper = styled(InfoIcon)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: fade(theme.palette.black, 0.3),
}));

export const GridWrapper = styled(Grid)(({ theme }) => ({
  pointerEvents: 'none',
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
}));

const DistributionLinePopover = ({ distributionLine }) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const handlePopoverOpen = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handlePopoverClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const mouseOverPopover = 'mouse-over-popover';
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Typography
        aria-owns={open ? mouseOverPopover : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onMouseEnter={handlePopoverOpen}
        onMouseOut={handlePopoverClose}
      >
        <InfoIconWrapper fontSize="small" />
      </Typography>
      <Popover
        id={mouseOverPopover}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        // onMouseOut={handlePopoverClose}
        disableRestoreFocus
      >
        <GridWrapper container>
         ...
        </GridWrapper>
      </Popover>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

How can I modify this code to make it behave as expected?  Originally I tried passing handlePopoverClose to popover, but that makes it so the popover closes only if you hover over the actual popover instead of hovering away from the 'i' icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found a solution.

In the Popover component, add this as a prop : style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}
and remove onMouseOut.

In the InfoIconWrapper component, add this as a prop onMouseLeave={handlePopoverClose}

Works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the anchorElem existence part of the open boolean state value. In fact, you don't need to check the anchorElem at all. There's a potential for race conditions when dealing with DOM element references.

I would change `setAnchorEl` to `setOpen`, and on enter call `setOpen` to `true`. You probably want like an "X" button to set open to `false` with an onClick event handler. I think technically, when a new element is rendered on top of the element that you hovered on, that "on mouse out" is triggered for the underlying element. See [this](https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave):

`According to the browser logic, the mouse cursor may be only over a single element at any time – the most nested one and top by z-index.`

Comment: Right, I see what you're saying.  Unfortunately, its a business requirement to have this designed exactly how the company wants it.  Material UI has a popover code snippet you can put directly into your component.  It works great, unfortunately, again, this team doesnt allow hooks in react and the only example from Material UI is a code snippet with a hook.  There should be a way to make it behave like theirs (I had to replace the hook with a styled component) but I can't figure it out.